# Change JSON property name on derived classes using Jackson library

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am using Spring to develop new REST API, I have `BaseResponse` class which acts as base responses for all response. this class contains attribute `String requestUuid;` at some cases this `requestUuid` must be serialized with attribute name `requestUuid` , on other cases it must be seriliazed as `request_uuid`, i know i can use `@JsonProperty` as a field level annotation, but it will affect all responses. is there is any way to override attribute name specifically for each one of the derived classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `@JsonProperty` on the method level instead. That way, you can override the field's getter method in the subclass and annotate that.

For example:

```
class BaseResponse {
    private String requestUuid;

    public getRequestUuid() {
        return requestUuid;
    }
}

class OtherResponse extends BaseResponse {
    @Override
    @JsonProperty("request_uuid")
    public getRequestUuid() {
        return super.getRequestUuid();
    }
}
```

Comment: the result JSON will have both fields "requestUuid" and "request_uuid". eg: {"requestUuid":uuid, "request_uuid":uuid}. If the result JSON should not want the parent field "requestUuid", then use @JsonIgnoreProperties({"requestUuid"}) then the result JSON will be {"request_uuid":uuid}

Answer (score 1):

You can send the field twice with different key names.

```
@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> otherFields() {
    Map<String, Object> otherFields = new HashMap<>();
    otherFields.put("requestUuid", this.requestUuid);
    otherFields.put("request_uuid", this.requestUuid);
    return otherFields;
}
```

Also, ignore your actual field:

```
@JsonIgnore
private String requestUuid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @JoshA response, another alternative is to define a constructor and annotate it. This leads to a more concise code by avoiding the need to override the getter methods in derived classes.

```java
class BaseResponse {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public BaseResponse(String firstName, String lastName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}

class OtherResponse extends BaseResponse {
    public OtherResponse(@JsonProperty("given_name") String firstName, @JsonProperty("family_name") String lastName) {
       super(firstName, lastName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

NO, its not possible, what is possible you can make new class for different type of requests.